# Android-How to open my app from the browser

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, intentfilter

I am developing a parental control app, the goal is, when certain websites are accessed, my app would pop up.

From my research, the way to accomplish this is by adding intent-filter to AndroidManifest.xml

For now my activity looks like this

```
<activity
     android:name=".BlockActivity"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <data android:scheme="http" />
     <data android:scheme="https" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

From my understanding, this should intercept any website access because I did not specify any host in data attributes. However, when I open, say, `www.google.com`, my activity does not start.

I also tried specifying the host like this, but it also did not work.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.google.com"/>
                <data android:pathPrefix="/"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Out of curiosity, I tried another intent-filter with `android.intent.action.SEND`, and it does trigger for sharing.

FYI, I am testing on a virtual device with API Level 30.

Any insights on my goal of intercepting web browsing are welcome, at this stage I am not even sure if intent-filter is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I later figured out that the better way of implementing what I'm trying to accomplish is to use [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService?hl=es).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).